# Add codebehind file to asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I got a file, let's call it MyPage.aspx. It has no codebehind and I need to add a codebehind file to it. Here's what I've done:

- created MyPage.aspx.cs and included it in the corresponding namespace
- Added the following code to the Page tag of MyPage.aspx: AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.MyPage"

Still, it doesn't work. I cannot access runat=server elements from the codebehind. Strangely, I also noticed one more thing:

The definition of the class in MyPage.aspx.cs is as follows:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Normally, both words MyPage and Page in this line would be green. However, only the word MyPage is green and the word Page is still black.

I'm kinda stuck with this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your project compile?

Comment: After adding `Code Behind` file, `RightClick on .aspx -> Select "Convert To Web Application" option`.

Comment: no, it doesnt compile. 

I don't see the Convert... button

Comment: You mentioned word Page is black. I suspect that references are not working properly. Try removing references and re-adding them. As suggestion, try to build file, close project and reopen it. It should work fine then.

Answer (score 1):

in your aspx page you need to regrence the code behind page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyPage" %>
```

after you do that, you make a new class and name it MyPage.aspx.cs, just make sure that its in the same directory as your aspx page.

also give the class name inside the code behind _MyPAge

it should look like this after you reference your components

```
public partial class _MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Hope this helps.